# Adding a second phrase to search for + the 10 following lines

Tags: search, text

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if 'searchphrase' in line:
            print line
```

Hi guy's,

So I have 1200 files to search through, in these 1200 files I need to -

- Copy the first line of every file into one new text document, followed by below.
- After pulling the first line of the document I need to search the rest of the file for my "Search phrase" - then copy that search phrase line along with the 10 following lines. Close file and move on to the next.

All the files are locate inside one master file, with uniform names.

Eg:

```
file 1
file 2
file 3
file 4
file 5 and so on...
```

I'v been trying for days but cannot seem to get it. This could save me 14 days of work.

Any help at all would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution!

```
with open("C:\file.txt") as infile, open("C:\outfile.txt", "w") as outfile:
    copy = False
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip() == "Start-Phrase":
            copy = True
        elif line.strip() == "End-Phrase":
            copy = False
        elif copy:
            outfile.write(line)
```